# Designing auto width & height attribute iOS app

Tags: ios

I'm complete novice to iOS.
This is I'm creating webview app which loads my mobile website.

While creating the app, I cam across `View` - `Show Alignment Rectangle` where I specified height & width of iPhone 6. Now when I run this for other iPhones, it was not able to resize to the width & height of that particular iPhone.

Is there anyway I can set those attributes to the `device-height` and `device-width`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use auto-layout...check out the tutorial here..
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1
and if you want device height and device width then

```
// get screensize
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

Comment: Yeah, solved it. Xcode was kind enough & applied the filters automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the concept of Adaptive Layouts, if you want to support your app for all the devices including iPads.

You can follow this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial).